# Convert PDF to GRAYSCALE format for printer from linux command line

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, command-line, grayscale

I'm trying to convert a PDF document to Grayscale, because I need the printer to recognize each page containing colors or not.

I'm using ghostscript from linux command line.

1. I convert PDF to PS to grep all the informations:

   pdftops -level3sep input.pdf

It generates a .ps file: input.ps

2. I convert this PS file to PDF again, converting it to grayscale with ghostscript:

   gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dColorConversionStrategy=/Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray input.ps

This command generates a PDF file.

When I open this last file, I see that all the pages are in grayscale. The command to test color pages says that are in grayscale, too:

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov output.pdf
```

For each page, it returned me CMYK values:

```
Page 1
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.92538 CMYK OK
Page 2
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.06737 CMYK OK
Page 3
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.63738 CMYK OK
Page 4
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.75010 CMYK OK
```

and so on... CMYK: 0,0,0,[something] -> each page is in grayscale.

**But when I go to print the document, the printer recognizes each page as sRGB and count them as color pages, not as grayscale pages.**

If i check each page with this script, it returns me that all the pages are sRGB, too:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
PAGES=$(pdfinfo ${FILE} | grep 'Pages:' | sed 's/Pages:\s*//')

GRAYPAGES=""
COLORPAGES=""
DOUBLECOLORPAGES=""

echo "Pages: $PAGES"
N=1
while (test "$N" -le "$PAGES")
do
    COLORSPACE=$( identify -format "%[colorspace]" "$FILE[$((N-1))]" )
    echo "$N: $COLORSPACE"
    if [[ $COLORSPACE == "Gray" ]]
    then
        GRAYPAGES="$GRAYPAGES $N"
    else
        COLORPAGES="$COLORPAGES $N"
        # For double sided documents also list the page on the other side of the sheet:
        if [[ $((N%2)) -eq 1 ]]
        then
            DOUBLECOLORPAGES="$DOUBLECOLORPAGES $N $((N+1))"
            #N=$((N+1))
        else
            DOUBLECOLORPAGES="$DOUBLECOLORPAGES $((N-1)) $N"
        fi
    fi
    N=$((N+1))
done

echo $DOUBLECOLORPAGES
echo $COLORPAGES
echo $GRAYPAGES
```

The result is:

```
andrea@release:~/fotocopia$ ./script.sh output.pdf
Pages: 4
1: sRGB
2: sRGB
3: sRGB
4: sRGB
1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

So the question is: how can I do to make the printer (rather than the script) recognize the pages as grayscale? Is there a method through linux command line that allows me to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution. I'm so sorry.

The problem was not related to the conversion by GhostScript, but to the software used to open the PDF file.

With the Chrome embedded PDF reader I had this problem, while with the original Adobe Reader plugin (overridden on chrome through chrome extensions) I was able to print correctly in greyscale and to let the printer recognize the format.

I hope this will help people with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the inkcov device always returns CMYK values, regardless of the colour space of the input. So the fact that it returns K channel values is correct.

Its pretty much impossible to guess at why your printer or script thinks that the pages are in sRGB without seeing the PDF file.

You should not double convert the PDF file, that is much more likely to introduce problems! You don't say what kind of information you are extracting with grep, but likely its available directly form the PDF file. If you want a grayscale PDF, then just convert the original PDF to a new PDF.

You also don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using to do this conversion, I seem to recall there was a bug in 9.15 which possibly had this effect. You might want to consider looking at the current code.

Comment: My GhostScript version is 9.10. The same problem remains even if i convert the file directly, without using the ps file step.

Comment: A version of GS that old won't properly remap the colours into the colour space you want, using the command line you've given. At the very least you would have to add -dUseCIEColor. I'd strongly recommend upgrading.

Comment: I upgraded ghostscript to version 9.14, but it seems to have the same problems. Niether the -dUseCIEColor does work. Any idea?

Comment: The current released version is 9.15, and 9.16 will be released within weeks. I would suggest that you use the current code, since I believe it works (you will have to clone the code from the git repository and build it yourself of course). Without seeing your input file its impossible for me to give any better advice. If you believe that the output PDF file is genuinely not being created as grayscale, then you could always open a bug report. You'll still have to supply the file though.